# Embedding local shiny web application into Excel file

Tags: r, excel, vba, webbrowser-control, shiny

I've tried to embed `shiny` page into Excel using Excel `Microsoft Web Control`, buttons, text etc. was displayed correctly, but no plot have been displayed, that not suprised me because of Web Socket issue with IE7/8 on which `Microsoft Web Control` is based. I wonder if there is any other way to directly embed `shiny` web application into Excel file. I found no Firefox based Web Controls, there is Geckofx project, but compiling it into ActiveX control is out of my scope of skills. Embedding `shiny` into Excel would be very useful for me because I would not need any new technology to deliver results for my internal firm clien except Excel and R.

If I put shiny web application into Excel file, all I would need is some additional VBA based wrapper for uploading data into it from spreadsheet directly, that gives me complete solution for building R based extensions for Excel which looks very good, and are easy to handle (more front-end oriented) in comparison to DDE or RExcel based solutions. R would run simply as local process on user machine.

**Edition**
Solution should work under Windows operating system, its version is irrelevant.

Comment: -2 vs 2 favorite, ergo help me to improve my question

Answer (score -1):

Could you consider using [Shiny Server](http://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/) to host the Shiny applications? Shiny Server provides compatibility with products that don't support WebSockets (like IE 8). I'm not sure if that's the issue with "Microsoft Web Control" or not, though.

Comment: I accept only MS compatible solutions, due to the fact this solution should serve for end users, Shiny Server is now not available on Windows platform

Comment: Then you should have said so in your question @Qbik.

Comment: You can consider VirtualBox to run Shiny Server on Windows. Alternatively, you could create your own proxy using the SockJS package we use in Shiny Server.